# Somar e exibir horário superior a 24 horas no Access 2007 VBA

Tags: vba, visual-basic-6, microsoft-access

Estou usando Access 2007 pra desenvolver um formulário de controle de garagem, onde consta informações sobre viagens feitas pelos motoristas.
Preciso calcular o total de tempo de cada viagem, e esse período pode ser superior a 24 horas.
Consegui calcular sem problemas quando o período é menor que 24 horas, mas constatei que o campo Date/Time do Access não consegue armazenar as informações que preciso nessa situação.
As informações do campo de horas calculadas são armazenadas em formato texto.

Segue meu código

Cálculo de Horas Comum:

```
Private Sub txtHoraChegada_LostFocus()
Dim HoraChegada As Date
Dim HoraSaida As Date
Dim HoraTotal As Date
Dim DataViagem As Date
Dim HorasCalculadas
Dim DiasCalculados

DataViagem = Me.txtDataViagem.Value
HoraChegada = Me.txtHoraChegada.Value
HoraSaida = Me.txtHoraSaida.Value

If HoraChegada < HoraSaida Then 'Verifica se a Hora de Chegada é MENOR que a Hora de Saída
    If HoraChegada = 0 Then 'Verifica se a Hora de Chegada foi meia noite
        HoraChegada = 24
        HoraTotal = DateAdd("h", HoraChegada, HoraSaida)
        DiasCalculados = DateAdd("d", 1, DataViagem)
    End If
    HoraTotal = ((HoraChegada - HoraSaida) + 24) * (-1)
    DiasCalculados = DateAdd("d", 1, DataViagem)
    MsgBox "O período da viagem é maior que 24h, a data de chegada foi ajustada", vbInformation, "Atenção" 'Mensagem ao usuário
End If

If HoraChegada = HoraSaida Then 'Verifica se a Hora de Chegada é igual à Hora de Saída
    HoraTotal = 24
    Dias = 1
    DiasCalculados = DateAdd("d", 1, DataViagem)
End If

If HoraChegada > HoraSaida Then 'Verifica se a Hora de Chegada é Maior que a Hora de Saída
    HoraTotal = HoraChegada - HoraSaida
    DiasCalculados = DataViagem
End If

Me.txtQtdeDias = Dias
Me.txtDuracaoTotal.Value = Format(HoraTotal, "hh:nn") 'Imprime o valor calculado da duração da viagem na caixa de texto
Me.txtDataChegada.Value = DiasCalculados 'Imprime a data de chegada do motorista na caixa de texto

End Sub
```

Fiz um botão que deveria adicionar um dia a mais (ou 24h) às horas já calculadas previamente

```
Private Sub btnMaisDias_Click()
  dteStart = txtDataViagem
  dteEnd = txtDataChegada
  Call DisplayHours((dteStart), (dteEnd))

End Sub
```

E essa é a função chamada pelo botão (dá erro de divisão por zero)

```
Public Function DisplayHours(dteStart As Date, dteEnd As Date) As String
    Dim lngMin As Long, lngHrs As Long
    lngMin = DateDiff("n", dteStart, dteEnd)
    lngHrs = lngMin / 60
    DisplayHours = lngHrs & ":" & Format(lngMin Mod lngHrs, "00")

End Function
```

Sou relativamente iniciante em programação, alguém consegue identificar o que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com algumas informações que achei por aí, o campo Date/Time do Access é incapaz de armazenar um valor maior que 24 horas, então fiz uma abordagem diferente.
Transformei o campo em um campo texto e fiz o cálculo da seguinte maneira.

```
Private Sub txtHoraChegada_LostFocus()
Dim HoraChegada As Date
Dim HoraSaida As Date
Dim HoraTotal As Date
Dim DataViagem As Date
Dim HorasCalculadas
Dim DiasCalculados
Dim horas, minutos
Dim interval

DataViagem = Me.txtDataViagem
HoraChegada = Me.txtHoraChegada
HoraSaida = Me.txtHoraSaida
DataChegada = Me.DataChegada

        If HoraChegada < HoraSaida Then 'Verifica se a Hora de Chegada é MENOR que a Hora de Saída
            If HoraChegada = 0 Then 'Verifica se a Hora de Chegada foi meia noite
                HoraChegada = 24
                HoraTotal = DateAdd("h", HoraChegada, HoraSaida)
                DiasCalculados = DateAdd("d", 1, DataViagem)
            End If
            HoraChegada = HoraChegada + 24
            HoraTotal = DateDiff("n", HoraSaida, HoraChegada)
        End If

        If HoraChegada = HoraSaida Then 'Verifica se a Hora de Chegada é igual à Hora de Saída
            HoraTotal = 24
            Dias = 1
            DiasCalculados = DateAdd("d", 1, DataViagem)
        End If

        If HoraChegada > HoraSaida Then 'Verifica se a Hora de Chegada é Maior que a Hora de Saída
            HoraTotal = HoraChegada - HoraSaida
            DiasCalculados = DataViagem
        End If


        interval = HoraChegada - HoraSaida
        Dias = DateDiff("d", DataViagem, DataChegada)
        horas = DateDiff("n", HoraViagem, HoraChegada)
        minutos = Int(CSng(interval * 1440)) Mod 60

        If Dias > 0 Then
            Me.txtDuracaoTotal.Value = Dias & " d " & Format(HoraTotal, "hh") & " h " & minutos & " m"
        Else
            Me.txtDuracaoTotal.Value = Format(HoraTotal, "hh") & " h " & minutos & " m"
        End If
        txtDuracaoTotal.SetFocus
End Sub
```